# Group rows and add sum column of unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, unique, rows

Here an example of my data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text='colA   colB   colC
10  11   7
10  34   7
10  89   7
10  21   7
2   23   5
2   21   5
2   56   5
22  14   3
22  19   3
22  90   3
11  19   2
11  45   2
1   45   0
1   23   0
9   8    0
9   11   0
9   21   0', header = TRUE)
```

I need to group the rows by `colA` and `colC` and add a new column which states the sum of unique values based on `colB`.

In steps here what I need to do for this specific data.frame:

- group rows with `colA` = 10 and 9, `colA` = 2 and 1, `colA` = 22 and `colA` = 11;
- find the unique values of `colB` per each group;
- add the unique values in a new col (`newcolD`).

Note that `colC` states the total number of observations for `colA` = 10 and 9, `colA` = 2 and 1, `colA` = 22 and `colA` = 11.
The data.frame needs to remain ordered decreasingly by `colC`.

My expected output is:

```
colA   colB   colC  newcolD
   10  11   7      5
   10  34   7      5
   10  89   7      5
   10  21   7      5
   9   8    0      5
   9   11   0      5
   9   21   0      5
   2   23   5      4
   2   21   5      4
   2   56   5      4
   1   45   0      4
   1   23   0      4
   22  14   3      3
   22  19   3      3
   22  90   3      3
   11  19   2      2
   11  45   2      2
```

To note that in `df` the `colB` duplicated values are: 11 and 21 for group 10 and 9, and 23 for group 2 and 1.

Comment: The conditional statement is not clear

Comment: You need to either rework this sentence: "For each colC diverse than zero group each colA value and its preceding one (i.e. 10 and 9, 2 and 1) and add a new column which states the sum of colB unique values (for each group)." . so it can be interpreted by native English speakers or you need to illustrate the procedure step by step so the intent can be inferred. There is no interpretation to the verb-object phrase: "diverse than zero each colA value".

Comment: Instead of getting defensive about comment, learn to monitor your questions and respond promptly and appropriately to constructive suggestions and DO NOT post duplicate followups. The number of points have nothing to do with the downvotes. They have to do with not using the site as recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `dplyr`. The trick is to create a new grouping column which groups consecutive values in colA. This is done with `cumsum(c(1, diff(colA) < -1)` in the example below.

```
df1 = read.table(text='colA   colB   colC
10  11   7
10  34   7
10  89   7
10  21   7
2   23   5
2   21   5
2   56   5
22  14   3
22  19   3
22  90   3
1   45   0
1   23   0
9   8    0
9   11   0
9   21   0', header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
arrange(desc(colA)) %>%
group_by(group_sequential = cumsum(c(1, diff(colA) < -1))) %>%
mutate(newcolD=n_distinct(colB))

    colA  colB  colC group_sequential newcolD
   <int> <int> <int>            <dbl>   <int>
1     22    14     3                1       3
2     22    19     3                1       3
3     22    90     3                1       3
4     10    11     7                2       5
5     10    34     7                2       5
6     10    89     7                2       5
7     10    21     7                2       5
8      9     8     0                2       5
9      9    11     0                2       5
10     9    21     0                2       5
11     2    23     5                3       4
12     2    21     5                3       4
13     2    56     5                3       4
14     1    45     0                3       4
15     1    23     0                3       4
```

**EDIT FOR NEW DATA**
With the data you added, we need to create a custom grouping. I use `case_when` in the example below. This matches the order you show in the desired output column. In the text, you wrote that you wanted the table to be sorted by colC. To do so, change the last line to `arrange(desc(colC))`

```
df1 = read.table(text='colA   colB   colC
10  11   7
10  34   7
10  89   7
10  21   7
2   23   5
2   21   5
2   56   5
22  14   3
22  19   3
22  90   3
11  19   2
11  45   2
1   45   0
1   23   0
9   8    0
9   11   0
9   21   0', header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(group_sequential = case_when(.$colA==10|.$colA==9~1,
                                      .$colA==2|.$colA==1~2,
                                      .$colA==22~3,
                                      .$colA==11~4)) %>%
mutate(newcolD=n_distinct(colB)) %>%
arrange(desc(newcolD))

    colA  colB  colC group_sequential newcolD
   <int> <int> <int>            <dbl>   <int>
1     10    11     7                1       5
2     10    34     7                1       5
3     10    89     7                1       5
4     10    21     7                1       5
5      9     8     0                1       5
6      9    11     0                1       5
7      9    21     0                1       5
8      2    23     5                2       4
9      2    21     5                2       4
10     2    56     5                2       4
11     1    45     0                2       4
12     1    23     0                2       4
13    22    14     3                3       3
14    22    19     3                3       3
15    22    90     3                3       3
16    11    19     2                4       2
17    11    45     2                4       2
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I will wait one/two days before mark it as best answer again.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am sure that the code works fine with my EXAMPLE df. but how can I extend it to my real data.frame with > 30,000 rows? is there any more generic function?

Comment: My first answer was a more generic version. The problem is that your grouping mechanism is custom. Why is 11 alone in its group but 10 and 9 are grouped together? For a long df, I would create a new grouping vector using `case_when` or `ifelse`. Unless there's a method to your grouping, there's no way around it.

Comment: ok, I will try. thank you and let's wait a bit for any other possible answer.....thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're really not making it easy for us, reposting slight variations of the same question instead of updating the old one and presenting conditions that are vague and inconsistent with what the desired output implies. Anyhow, here is my attempt. This is more an answer to the [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055832/group-weird-data-frame-and-add-column?noredirect=1#comment73215331_43055832) you posted, as that was a bit more general in form.

It's a bit messy, it's pretty much a direct translation of your conditions into a for loop with some if statements. I chose to focus on your written conditions rather than the expected output as that was the easier one to understand. If you want a better answer, please consider cleaning up you question(s) considerably.

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
  colA colB colC
    10   11    7
    10   34    7
    10   89    7
    10   21    7
    2    23    5
    2    21    5
    2    56    5
    22   14    3
    22   19    3
    22   90    3
    11   19    2
    11   45    2
    1    45    0
    1    23    0
    9    8     0
    9    11    0
    9    21    0", header=TRUE)

df2 <-  read.table(text="
  colA colB colC
    10   11    7
    10   34    7
    10   89    7
    10   21    7
    2    23    5
    2    21    5
    2    56    5
    33   24    3
    33   78    3
    22   14    3
    22   19    3
    22   90    3
    11   19    2
    11   45    2
    1    45    0
    1    23    0
    9    8     0
    9    11    0
    9    21    0
    32   11    0", header=TRUE)

df <- df1
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
            df$colD[i] <- ifelse(df$colC[i] == 0,
      0,
      length(unique(df$colA[1:i])))

    if (any(df$colA[i]-1 == df$colA[1:i]) & df$colC[i] != 0) {
        df$colD[i] <- df$colD[which(df$colA[i]-1 == df$colA[1:i])][1]
    }
}

# colA colB colC colD
#   10   11    7    1
#   10   34    7    1
#   10   89    7    1
#   10   21    7    1
#    2   23    5    2
#    2   21    5    2
#    2   56    5    2
#   22   14    3    3
#   22   19    3    3
#   22   90    3    3
#   11   19    2    1
#   11   45    2    1
#    1   45    0    0
#    1   23    0    0
#    9    8    0    0
#    9   11    0    0
#    9   21    0    0

df <- df2
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
            df$colD[i] <- ifelse(df$colC[i] == 0,
      0,
      length(unique(df$colA[1:i])))

    if (any(df$colA[i]-1 == df$colA[1:i]) & df$colC[i] != 0) {
        df$colD[i] <- df$colD[which(df$colA[i]-1 == df$colA[1:i])][1]
    }
}
df
# colA colB colC colD
#   10   11    7    1
#   10   34    7    1
#   10   89    7    1
#   10   21    7    1
#    2   23    5    2
#    2   21    5    2
#    2   56    5    2
#   33   24    3    3
#   33   78    3    3
#   22   14    3    4
#   22   19    3    4
#   22   90    3    4
#   11   19    2    1
#   11   45    2    1
#    1   45    0    0
#    1   23    0    0
#    9    8    0    0
#    9   11    0    0
#    9   21    0    0
#   32   11    0    0
```

To also group the rows where `colC` is zero, it's sufficient to adjust the conditionals like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$colD[i] <- length(unique(df$colA[1:i]))

    if (any(df$colA[i]-1 == df$colA[1:i])) {
        df$colD[i] <- df$colD[which(df$colA[i]-1 == df$colA[1:i])][1]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort @AkselA but this is not right. I need also colC observations = 0 marked in the new column

Comment: Then what was all that 'different from 0' talk about?

Comment: I am sorry but it seems no one is understanding me. don't waste your time with this question..bye

Comment: @aaaaa: I added a version that treats all the rows, irrespective of `colC` value.

Comment: still not correct....the 0s rows have a relation with the other ones...see my expected output above and instead of 5,4,3,2 in newcolD, think about 1,2,3,4 as you did in your answers..